# How do I manipulate a file within an archive in Groovy/Gradle?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a jar file on my filesystem and I want to update a value in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF. Is there a way to manipulate that file without having to unpack it and then repack it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle's Jar task doesn't provide such an option yet, but it's easy to use the Ant Jar task from Gradle.

Comment: I've taken a look at the docs for the jar ant task and it's not clear to me how this is done using ant either. It seems, just like with Gradle, that I can unzip, modify, then zip it up again. But I don't see how I can do it in place. If you could in rough terms describe how, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: From the docs for the [Ant Jar task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html): [...] _The update parameter controls what happens if the JAR file already exists. [...]_

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TrueZip (http://truezip.java.net/features.html). It seems to be able to do what you want.